# Can't access internet via browser(on ANY device), yet can ping/traceroute/curl/wget/telnet successfully

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

Been without internet access for days now, received THREE replacement routers from ISP, still no luck. If I open a browser(chrome, safari, firefox), on any device(android, iphone, windows, macbook), when I try to navigate to a website, I receive an ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED(though on the phones it just says no internet access). I can log in to the router(s), change settings, see connected clients, etc. Everything seems normal.

The model of these routers are C4000BG, they are modem/router combos. This issue appeared out of nowhere after 8 months of no interruptions(I was literally out of the apartment between when it was working, and when it stopped working). I am at a total loss, as a very tech savvy individual I've always been able to solve wifi issues, but this one has me stumped. I can do a wget or a curl (https & http) request to various websites, and receive the content. I can do a traceroute that will succeed, and ping the website as well(this is not a DNS issue). I have checked with the ISP and they confirmed I don't have any kind of DMCA or suspicious activity causing this problem. The DSL line the router uses is stable, with no issues(according to ISP supervisor I talked with after hours of troubleshooting with various departments). I was even able to connect to the ProtonVPN free server, but got the same error when attempting to browse the internet. I can telnet to ports 80 & 443 successfully to various websites, but not browse. This is for ALL devices I have, and I cannot make sense of it.

Was told to post this here instead of at Network Engineering.

Comment: Most ISP techs have a computer with them. Ask them to come back and show how you can get it working.

Comment: They will be here in a few days, but I WFH so I was hoping there was another solution.

Comment: Can you expand your question to advise what you have checked with respect of DNS?

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping google.com? or were your ping/telnet tests to IPs?

Have you tried using nslookup to check DNS resolution?

If DNS resolution is not working try chaning your DNS server to 1.1.1.1

Have you tested ethernet and wifi directly on the router?

If you only use WiFi try to remove and re-add the WiFi network to your device.
Is your public IP showing as expected? Check your public IP with this powershell command

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing ifconfig.me/ip).Content.Trim()
```

Have you tried something like this to check http is working?

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing superuser.com
```

Comment: Yes to all those questions. I believe I may be being throttled as I was able to access web pages with a barebones terminal browser. Or certain user agents are being blocked? It's confusing

Comment: @FrigidDev have you gotten any friends to replicate the issue?
Did the ISP come and take a look yet and what was the result?

Comment: A tech came, it took him two days of fiddling with wires. In the end they completely recreated everything, from account down to new physical connections, and that did the trick. He said he had never seen anything like it, called several people they hadn't either! Very strange

Comment: So the issue was on their end ay... classic ISP move haha